# Vue-leaflet and vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet, vuetify.js

I have a issue with vue-leaflet and vuetyfy. I have simple template which show different layout depends on mobile or not. If app detect mobile I want to make 2 row layout, first map, second for input form. But the map occupy all screen space and input form show above this map. My second layout for desktop screen work fine, I just set w-50 class to map and that all. I've tried to set h-50 to the map, but it doesn't work as expected. How to fix this issue?

My layout looks like this:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid v-if="mobile">
    <v-row class="mb-5">
      <v-col class="pl-0">
        <Map marker="true" />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <AddPlaceDescription />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <Footer />
  </v-container>

  <v-container fluid v-else>
    <v-row>
      <v-col class="px-0">
        <Map class_attr="w-50" marker="true" />
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <AddPlaceDescription />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <Footer />
  </v-container>
</template>
```

This is my Map component

```
<template>
  <l-map
    id="themap"
    :class="class_attr"
    :zoom="zoom"
    :center="center"
    @update:zoom="zoomUpdated"
    @update:center="centerUpdated"
    @update:bounds="boundsUpdated"
  >
    <l-tile-layer :url="url" ></l-tile-layer>

    <v-marker-cluster>
      <l-marker
        v-if="marker"
        ref="marker"
        draggable
        @dragend="onDragEnd"
        :latLng="center"
      ></l-marker>
      <l-marker
        v-for="marker in markersData"
        :key="marker['latLng'][0]"
        :lat-lng="marker['latLng']"
      >
        <l-popup><a href="#">{{marker['description']}}</a></l-popup>
      </l-marker>
    </v-marker-cluster>
  </l-map>
</template>
```

AddPlaceDescription component

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col class="ml-3">
      <v-alert
        v-if="showMsg"
        border="left"
        :color="msgColor"
        outlined
        text
        type="error"
        >{{ msg }} {{countDown}} </v-alert
      >
      <form action="">
        {{ this.$store.state.Map.markerLatLng }}
        <v-textarea
          outlined
          name="place-description"
          label="Description"
          v-model="description"
          :disabled='showMsg'
        ></v-textarea>
        <v-btn @click="sendPoint" :disabled='showMsg'>Send</v-btn>
        <v-btn @click="clearForm" :disabled='showMsg'>Clear</v-btn>
      </form>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

and result like this

[image: and result like this]

Comment: Could it be that your Map component is positioned absolutely? It could explain why the form appears on top of the map. What is the CSS applied to it?

Unrelated to your issue with the layout on mobile: To avoid duplicate code, I would recommend having one v-container instead of two and make use of the grid system instead: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/

Comment: @valentin, I updated my question, add components code there. Now you can see, I don't use any custom css style. My map component has fixed position when I see it via browser developer tool. I've tried to play with position in developer tool, but wasn't successful. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

So I've break it yahoooo)) I just interchange the position of components and it works as expected. Of course I want to description component below the map, but anyway it is better than nothing.